# Rails 4 - Display data inside a bootstrap modal via ajax Does not change id :

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a list of books displayed in view books/index , This is the code in the _book_row.html.erb where I want to add link to amazon price compare to show Amazon's price of selected book and I want to show it in bootstrap modal. I am very new to rails and not very familiar with ajax as well.

This is what I have so far,

```
<%= link_to "Compare to Amazon" , amazon_price_path(book.id), remote: true %>
```

In my books_controller

```
  def amazon_price
    @book= Book.find(params[:id])
    @search_term = @book.isbn
    search_term = @search_term.delete("^a-zA-Z  0-9")
    @price  = Amazon::Ecs.item_search(search_term,  { :response_group => 'Offers', :search_index => 'Books', :sort => 'relevancerank' })
    @price.items.each_with_index do |item, n|
      @amazon_price = item.get('OfferSummary/LowestNewPrice/FormattedPrice')
      break
   end
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
 end
```

My route

```
  match '/amazon_price/:id',
    to:   'books#amazon_price',
    via:  'get',
    as:   :amazon_price
```

in views/books/_amazon_price.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body"> 

         <h1>MODAL BODY</h1>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in views/books/amazon_price.js.erb

```
$('body').append('<%= j render partial: "amazon_price" %>');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

And yes its shows price of from amazon as I want it to be ***the issue is I need to show price for every book .When I click on first book I get the correct price but for every subsequent book click I get the same price (Whats going wrong here)***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the page, you probably have multiple modals being stacked because you are not deleting the old ones.  Try something like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

This will add a listener to the event fired when the modal is hidden, and will remove the modal from the DOM when it completes.